# Add UnityEngine.dll to Mono projects on a Mac

Tags: monodevelop, unity-game-engine

When building Mono DLLs for use in Unity we want to reference the UnityEngine.dll. Several tutorials talk through how to do this. For example here are the instructions from [the Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/UsingDLL.html)

> Next, you should add references to the Unity DLLs. In MonoDevelop, you
> should open the contextual menu For References in the Solution Browser and
> choose Edit References. Then, choose the option .Net Assembly tab > File
> System > select file. [...]
>
> At this stage, you will have the option to select the required DLL file.   >On Mac OSX, the file can be found at
>
> Applications/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed/UnityEngine.dll

But the Mac finder will not step into Unity.app so I cannot navigate into that folder to choose UnityEngine.dll. I can navigate there in the terminal, but not in the 'select file' finder. How do I add UnityEngine.dll as a reference in a Mono project on a Mac?

Comment: I'm not sure this is right for Stack Overflow. Would it be better on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like `MonoDevelop` does not set the file browser to include `.app` and thus does not present `Show Package Contents` in the right-click context menu.

Use **`CMD-Shift-G`** to popup the **Go to the folder:** entry, enter `/Applications/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Managed` and select `Go`

[image]